# Code stops working when I add a function call but works when I remove the call

Tags: javascript, function, socket.io, addeventlistener

This code works. It changes the button color without any problem

```
   document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 49) {
     

      button1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
     
      setTimeout(() => {
       button2.style.border = "";
       button1.style.backgroundColor = "";
          
          console.log("changed style ")

      }, 100);
      getDate();
   }
```

But when I add **socket.Emit("hello","world")** It throws the error "*getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')*" it can no longer change the color of button1.

```
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 49) {
      socket.emit("hello" , "world") <= When this is added

      button1.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"; <= Error is caused by this line
     
      setTimeout(() => {
       button2.style.border = "";
       button1.style.backgroundColor = "";
          
          console.log("changed style ")

      }, 100);
      getDate();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Button1 is not being defined thus it cannot apply a style to it. Please provide more code or look back and properly define it.

Comment: const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
 it is working in the first code example it is just when I add the **socket.emit("hello" , "world") ** line is when the button starts being undefined.

Comment: Well im not sure. Can you provide the entire script because these have no correlation to each other.